# MKMapAnnotaion view callout contains tableview and uitableviewcells are not accessible

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkmapitem

I want to set Accessibility label for uitableviewcell. When i add tableview as MKMapViewAnnotation content I am not able to select tableviewcell through accessibility. When I debug tableview inside MKMapAnnotation isAccessible is always NO and tableviewcell inside MKMapAnnotation isAccessible is Yes. Please help me to set isAccessible of tableview to Yes. I tried in milliion ways to set but tableview is not accessible.

**Fot Tableview:**

```
 _tableview.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
```

**For UITableviewcell :**

```
cell.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
NSString *accessibilitytext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",cell.textLabel.text,cell.detailTextLabel.text];
cell.accessibilityLabel = accessibilitytext;
```

**For viewForAnnotaion:**

```
MKAnnotationView* view =    [((NSObject<AnnotationProtocol>*)annotation) annotationViewInMap:self.mapView]
view.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, please go through this once.

https://github.com/grgcombs/MultiRowCalloutAnnotationView

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am able to run you application. When voice over is on we cannot touch the rows inside callout view. My requirement here itself is making rows accessible when voiceover is on.

Comment: have you checked single and double touch when voice over is on? single for description and double for selection.

Comment: yes. I cannot single touch any tablecell when in map annotation. cell is not easily interactable. I have to apply pressure and select the cell.

Comment: Satish A  I know single touch for accessibility and double touch for selection. But single touch for accessibility not working in map annotaion

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create complete custom callout from XIB and handle everything inside callout view as a regular UIView

Check out the example: [GitHub](https://github.com/alex4Zero/AZCustomCallout)

Comment: Sorry. I am doing Big application and all the components are already done. I only need to set accessibility. There is some solution here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW5. But I am not able to put the chunks of code relative to my MKMapAnnotation.